# Loudspeaker Efficiency

Tags: speakers

The nameplate or nominal impedance of most modern speakers is 4 or 8 ohms. It has been known for generations that the actual impedance varies somewhat with frequency and is not pure resistance. Amplifiers are designed with this in mind. The DC resistance measured with a DVM is about 6 ohm for an 8 ohm speaker and about 3 ohm for a 4 ohm speaker. This observed ratio of DCR to speaker impedance appears to be relatively constant and has not changed for many decades. Surely this means that 75% of the audio power is wasted before the mechanical and acoustic matching losses occur. Loudspeaker efficiency is important when considering low power equipment.

So my questions are: Are modern speakers more efficient? And why don't they make a speaker with lower DCR with a thicker lower DCR voice coil with the better permanent magnet materials available?

Comment: I don't think modern speakers are more efficient. But it's just an ignorant opinion. I have some old headphones, for example, where the efficiency seems higher than pretty much anything you can buy today (without spending thousands of dollars.) They used to carefully wind thousands of windings of very fine wire. I've one that tests at 160+ dB SPL. That was with the crappy permanent magnets they had available back then, which are nothing nearly as good when compared to what you can get today. But back then crystal sets were more common. So needs have changed, too. Maybe I'll learn something.

Comment: _"Surely this means that 75% of the audio power is wasted before ..."_ - I'm not sure how you reached that conclusion... Could you explain why you think that?

Comment: Not all transducers from electric power to something audible by humans are dynamic ("voice coil"): *Revolutionary motor-driven belt design increases linear excursion and efficiency, handles large low-frequency peaks without damage or sonic compromise.* (Thomas Danley, e.g. *BassTech 7*) (Might not overlap *low power equipment*.)

Answer (score 3):

If we compare two speakers of identical diameter and voice coil area, mounted in the same enclosure to eliminate differences in efficiency due to loading, horns, etc... besides resistive losses, most of the power goes into accelerating the loudspeaker cone back and forth, braking it, then accelerating it in the other direction, etc.

This means efficiency strongly depends on **moving mass** (voice coil, former, cone, dustcap, etc).

So, high efficiency requires a very light moving mass, but then it is more difficult to make the cone **stiff** and **properly damped**.

There is always a compromise between stiffness, damping, moving mass, and cost.

If it is too light yet stiff, it'll lack damping, so it'll ring, exhibit bad sounding breakup modes, and maybe fail if someone cranks the volume to 11 and the speaker bottoms out. More damping reduces efficiency, and it also increases mass because it requires more material. If you still want it light, stiff, well damped, good sounding and efficient, then you'll need more expensive materials.

Also (and this is important)... say you make a very efficient speaker, now you have to put it in an enclosure. Then if you do the math...

It is quite easy to have good efficiency at frequencies above, say, 2-300Hz. However, efficiency at lower frequencies requires much more enclosure volume. Basically you want all the springs (loudspeaker surround, spider, and air in the enclosure) to not be stiff so less power has to be expended to push the speaker cone against these spring forces. And if you want the air in a box to have lots of compliance, then you need a very big volume of it. This is why audiophiles with flea powered tube amps that still get great bass often have washing-machine sized speakers.

[image]

...and if you don't want a huge cabinet, then either you'll have to sacrifice bass extension and cut at 70Hz, or bass efficiency will be lower. Now, if you use a passive crossover and want the woofer and mid/tweeter to be well balanced, then you will have to pick drivers with the same efficiency as your woofer.... and the usual problem is, unless you build a washing machine sized box, the midrange/tweeter is usually too efficient so it has to be padded with a resistor to match the woofer! (or use active crossover)

So you see, it's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are hypothesising 25% efficiency from the DCR aspect alone : that is still at least an order of magnitude higher than the overall efficiency which is what matters.

The upshot is that if you improve that aspect, you make something else worse, and the overall efficiency declines.

For example, you may attempt to reduce DCR by increasing the voice coil wire gauge : it is now lower resistance, but much heavier. It takes more power to move the coil to the same deflection.

Or reduce the number of turns, keeping the same coil mass. Now to keep the magnetic field strength (Ampere-turns) the same to produce the same driving force, you need more amperes.

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

The measured DC resistance has very little to do with rated impedance, which is the impedance given at some specific frequency ( or range of frequencies), and speakers are not driven with DC. Besides the impedance is usually given just with no decimals so the rated impedance is just nominal typical value anyway which gives enough information to know it if is compatible with the amplifier you are using.

In theory, most efficient speaker would have 0 ohm coil and they would be current driven elements. But for legacy and practical reasons the coils have resistance and they are voltage driven, so to have compatibility with speakers and amplifiers.

Better magnets do affect speaker efficiency, it is just measured with the parameter of speaker sensitivity, which gives you how loud it is with given power. For example typical speaker could be a loud as 80 dB SPL when given 1 watt and measured at 1 meter. A more sensitive speaker with 83 dB/W would be double as loud with same input power.